# Show/Hide DIV element generated through a while loop individually

Tags: javascript, php

I have been reviewing previous forums and I am aware of similar questions however I failed to find what exactly I need. In a nutshell I have a while loop and this while loop generates hide/show div elements depending on the quantity of records there exists in a specific table. What I want to accomplish is for the user to be able to individually access each div.

Here is the script file being used:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function show()   
 {

     var x=document.getElementById('woupdate7');
     if(x.style.display==='none')
     {
        x.style.display='block';
     }
    else
     {
        x.style.display='none'; 
     }

 }
</script>
```

Then the php code is as follows:

```
$woeditquery="SELECT * FROM 3pxwotc_tb where woid='$worderindex' and 
wosct<>''";
$woeditresult=mysqli_query($con6,$woeditquery);
while($woeditrecord2=mysqli_fetch_array($woeditresult))
{
echo "<div id='woupdate6'>";
echo"<label><img src='images/darrow.png' style='padding-left:3px;padding-
top:3px; width: 20px; height: 20px; margin:0' 
onclick='show()'>Details:</label>";
echo"</div>";
 //===================================================================

echo"<div id='woupdate7' style='display:none'>";
echo"<br><textarea name='reason' id='adres' rows='3' 
cols='135'placeholder='Enter Details'></textarea><br>";
echo"</div>";
}
```

The above code will only show the first hide/show div element, rightly so because I am only specifying the same div/element by the same ID name.

I changed the java code as follows replacing ID to CLASS:

```
function show()   
 {

     var x=document.getElementsByClassName("woupdate7");
     n = x.length;
     for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) 
     {
     var e = x[i];
         if(e.style.display==='none')
     {
         e.style.display='block';
     }
     else
     {
        e.style.display='none'; 
     }

 }
</script>
```

and then in my php code a changed to .class. This code show/hide elements simultaneously which is not what I want either.

Can someone enlighten me how can I achieve individual show/hide elements within a set? I would appreciate greatly.

I am aware what is it required, in a way I need to index each and every individual hide/show element, the problem is that I do not know exactly how it is achieved.

Thank you as always.

Comment: Which elements should then be shown, when clicking on the link. If its not the first and not all, which one? Clicking on `woupdate6` will show `woupdate7`? Try to give them some attribute in common, then your task would be much easier. You could use for example a `data`-attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if that is what you need but anyways... this toggles the details of each individual item

```js
[].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.toggleDetails')).forEach(function(e){e.onclick = function(){
 this.parentElement.querySelector('.details').classList.toggle('hidden')
}})
```

```css
.item{
  margin:5px;
  border:1px solid #efefef;
  padding:5px;
}
.hidden{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <div class="title">Item 1</div>
  <div class="details hidden">
    Edit Details
    <input name="details" />
  </div>
  <span class="toggleDetails">Details</span>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <div class="title">Item 2</div>
  <div class="details hidden">
    Edit Details
    <input name="details" />
  </div>
  <span class="toggleDetails">Details</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Levi, thanks however although you can access the divs seperately, this is not what I am looking for. Simply because the amount of Div elements will be a variable dependent on a table.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the index with a counter variable in the same loop. Add this:

`"<div id='woupdate". $counter ."'>"`

And at the end of the loop increment the counter:

`$counter++;`

If instead of printing the result in the same loop you store the string in a variable to print it later you can use the same loop to build a menu or select to navigate through te divs later. Use concatenate to store the string, like:

`$output .= "<div id='woupdate". $counter ."'>";`

And build the select, something like:

`$select .= "<a href='#woupdate". $counter ."'>"woupdate". $counter ."</a>";`

Then you can print these varaibles in their place. Remember to define the variables before the while:

`$counter = 0;
$select = "";
$output = "";`

This is just one way to do it, depending on how you want to navigate through the divs it may change.

**Update:**

Using links and ids like in the previous example you don't need to use JavaScript to hide / show the divs, you can do it with css like this:

```css
nav {
  width: 100%;
}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}

nav a:after {
  content:' | ';
}

.container div {
  display: none;
}

div:target {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="#woupdate1">woupdate1</a>
  <a href="#woupdate2">woupdate2</a>
  <a href="#woupdate3">woupdate3</a>
</nav>

<div class="container">
<div id="woupdate1">
<h1>woupdate1</h1>
Bacon ipsum dolor amet hamburger flank turducken, drumstick andouille short loin meatball picanha pork chop capicola sirloin ham hock pork loin bacon porchetta. Rump meatball bresaola pork belly sausage tongue. Biltong spare ribs pork chop, sausage ball tip tenderloin cow hamburger pork shoulder chuck. Ham hock spare ribs tongue drumstick andouille cow rump meatball, corned beef turducken flank prosciutto jerky. Leberkas salami strip steak shoulder.
</div>

<div id="woupdate2">
<h1>woupdate2</h1>
Drumstick boudin ham tri-tip kielbasa ground round pancetta alcatra ham hock short loin landjaeger. Tongue ground round salami jerky biltong pork andouille ribeye flank sausage doner. Shoulder hamburger sirloin drumstick kielbasa salami sausage pork. Shank pastrami salami pork loin tenderloin kielbasa filet mignon t-bone prosciutto cupim bacon ground round. Doner meatball swine capicola leberkas porchetta pork pig jerky turducken tail.
</div>

<div id="woupdate3">
<h1>woupdate3</h1>
Tongue jowl pastrami, shoulder bacon salami prosciutto boudin tenderloin kielbasa chuck pork loin. Corned beef rump pastrami, picanha ball tip shankle leberkas cow tenderloin salami hamburger jowl venison ham hock beef. Ham hock ribeye swine picanha. Boudin cow sausage doner pork loin pork chop t-bone, fatback capicola shankle chicken corned beef kielbasa. Spare ribs tongue turkey kielbasa short ribs leberkas meatloaf shank.
</div>
</div>
```

All the divs start hidden, we can use the `:target` selector to show them when the link is clicked.

You can do it using JavaScript, e.g:

```js
$(".container div:first-child").show();

$("select").change(function() {
  $(".container div").hide();
  $($("select option:selected").val()).show();
});
```

```css
    nav {
      width: 100%;
    }

    nav a {
      text-decoration: none;
      font-weight: bold;
    }

    nav a:after {
      content:' | ';
    }

    .container div {
      display: none;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <select>
      <option value="#woupdate1">woupdate1</option>
      <option value="#woupdate2">woupdate2</option>
      <option value="#woupdate3">woupdate3</option>
    </select>

    <div class="container">
    <div id="woupdate1">
    <h1>woupdate1</h1>
    Bacon ipsum dolor amet hamburger flank turducken, drumstick andouille short loin meatball picanha pork chop capicola sirloin ham hock pork loin bacon porchetta. Rump meatball bresaola pork belly sausage tongue. Biltong spare ribs pork chop, sausage ball tip tenderloin cow hamburger pork shoulder chuck. Ham hock spare ribs tongue drumstick andouille cow rump meatball, corned beef turducken flank prosciutto jerky. Leberkas salami strip steak shoulder.
    </div>

    <div id="woupdate2">
    <h1>woupdate2</h1>
    Drumstick boudin ham tri-tip kielbasa ground round pancetta alcatra ham hock short loin landjaeger. Tongue ground round salami jerky biltong pork andouille ribeye flank sausage doner. Shoulder hamburger sirloin drumstick kielbasa salami sausage pork. Shank pastrami salami pork loin tenderloin kielbasa filet mignon t-bone prosciutto cupim bacon ground round. Doner meatball swine capicola leberkas porchetta pork pig jerky turducken tail.
    </div>

    <div id="woupdate3">
    <h1>woupdate3</h1>
    Tongue jowl pastrami, shoulder bacon salami prosciutto boudin tenderloin kielbasa chuck pork loin. Corned beef rump pastrami, picanha ball tip shankle leberkas cow tenderloin salami hamburger jowl venison ham hock beef. Ham hock ribeye swine picanha. Boudin cow sausage doner pork loin pork chop t-bone, fatback capicola shankle chicken corned beef kielbasa. Spare ribs tongue turkey kielbasa short ribs leberkas meatloaf shank.
    </div>
    </div>
```

I used JQuery for simplicity. All divs start hidden using css, the first line of JS shows the first div, then selecting each options hides all divs and shows the selected one.

To follow this example you need to build options instead of a links in the php code:

`$select .= "<option value='#woupdate". $counter ."'>"woupdate". $counter ."</option>";`

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks, however I believe some changes needs to be done on the javascript file as well. Do you have any ideas? Thanks

Comment: @R.Cremona I've just updated the answer with a couple of ideas, one using simple css navigation, and the other with JS.